# Dynamic Currency Formating in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, atg, currency-formatting

How to align dynamic Currency accordingly to the Currency format?

Example:
if currency has dollar it should be left aligned ($ 100)
if currency has euro it should be right aligned (100 gbp)

Is there any best possible way we can bring this out.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where is currency sign positioned usually?

Comment: euro Isn't displayed like that, its the same as dollar eg. €5,-. And I think if you use symbols for currency its (almost) always in front of the number.

Comment: @EpicKip In France we write it `500 €` (or 500 EUR). Source: [monnaies](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Conventions_typographiques#Devises_.28monnaie.29)

Comment: if you write is in words its the same for $, not specific to the currency. I can write 500 USD and its correct same as you could do €500 and it be considered correct. I'd say just put them all right side or all left side, it gets messy if the symbols are all over the place

Comment: @Banzay - the currency sign is positioned according to the country defined.

Comment: @EpicKip - as mentioned above in the Source: [monnaies](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Conventions_typographiques#Devises_.28monnaie.29) by FelipeAls, the symbol comes after the amount.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the front-end with JavaScript etc? Since you are using ATG, you can use the `CurrencyTagConverter` in the `valueof` tag when you generate the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In ATG you could use

```
<dsp:valueof param="amount" converter="currency" locale="en_US" />
```

Or if you want to do it with Javascript, there is this library: http://numeraljs.com/ check the currency sector.